# Conditionally match, but without extra space

Tags: php, regex

This regex: http://regexr.com/3a9id matches correctly:

```
create 5 pages
create 5
```

But it does include an space, like this: " pages".

How can I avoid that space, but also match on `create 5`?

Using this regex:

```
/create ([1-9]{1,3})([^\s]|.*)/ig
```

See: http://regexr.com/3a9ij

*Bonus question: how can I make it only work with positive integers? i.e. not match on `create 0`?*

Comment: `#^create ([1-9][0-9]{0,2})$#gm`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like this:

`/create ([1-9]{1,}(?:[0-9]{0,})) ?(.*)/g`

Example: http://regexr.com/3a9iv

`([1-9]{1,}(?:[0-9]{0,}))` Matches a single digit number (from 1 to 9), maybe followed by other digits (to match numbers > 9) in a non-capturing group.

`?(.*)`
Matches a space if present, followed by anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
create 0*([1-9]\d*) *(.*)
```

only matches if the number is greater than 0.

[regex101 demo.](https://regex101.com/r/eB4dB9/1)